# How to Save Different Settings Options Using Settings API and/or the Theme Optimizer

Tags: options, settings-api, customization, theme-customizer

I would like to allow users to save different versions in the options panel using the Settings API and/or the Theme Optimzer.

For instance, imagine that I have styled my site using via an admin panel or the theme optimizer.  I like how it looks, but I want to experiment with a different look.  The problem is that I don't want to lose the work that I have done.

What I would like to be able to do is to name and save these styles and be able to reload them later on and use or edit them.  Is that possible vis-a-vis the Settings API and/or the Theme Optimizer - and, if so, how could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar as an import/export facility. Essentially I created a Theme Options Import/Export page in the dashboard, then just export the theme options (using `get_option()`) to a file as a JSON encoded string and post it for the user to download. Then give them an upload facility the imports said file (using `update_option()`). You could do the same thing just by storing different numbered options rather than saving it to a file.